# Newbie to emacs. need help

Tags: linux, fedora

Are there any good resources that anyone can suggest. I rate myself 3 out of 10 when it comes to using editors like vim

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please do a web search for "emacs tutorial" and you will come across a number of useful resources.  This forum is designed for discrete questions rather than open-ended ones.

Comment: The answer is "yes".  You may want to rephrase it in order to clarify if you want a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

I write up something like the canonical answer.

If you have Emacs with graphical environment such as X11 or Windows just start Emacs and open the menu item `Help` → `Emacs Tutorial` with the help of your pointing device such as mouse or touchpad.

If you only have the command line version of emacs start emacs with the following command line:

`emacs -f help-with-tutorial`

Then fight your way through the tutorial.

PS: This answer is marked as community wiki. So do not hesitate to improve it in any way.